# python import one directory file out of two

Tags: python, import

For example:

```
 Files/ 
    main.py
    SubFileA/
        __init__.py              "from util1 import help"
        util1.py                 "def help(): print ...A..."
    SubFileB/
        __init__.py              "from util1 import help"
        util1.py                 "def help(): print ...B..."
```

and util1.py in SubFileA and SubFileB has different content.

I want to have some way users can specify which util1.py to be imported.

I am expecting something like:

```
  if subFileA:
       from SubFileA import *
  else:
       from SubFileB import *
```

util1.py has a same API, but the implementation is different.

Reason of why I am doing this, because if I combine two util1.py together, the code will get ugly and hard to maintain. Hoping anyone can give me a solution to this, or any advice will be great!

I try those code, but I got warning (it does work, but the warning is embarrassing):

```
main.py:4: SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level
   def main():
main.py:4: SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level
   def main():
```

---

everyone. I guess I found the solution. But it is not good programming style I think.

```
Files/
   main.py                              "from directory import *"
   directory/
       __init__.py                      
                                        "user=raw_input() 
                                        if user: 
                                              from directoryA import *
                                        else
                                              from directoryB import * "
       directoryA/
           __init__.py                   "from util1 import help1()"
           util1.py 
       directoryB/
           __init__.py                   "from util1 import help1()"
           util1.py
```

Indeed, this looks very strange. But it does the job.

Comment: is there only one file in both SubFileA and SubFileB?

Comment: What you wrote looks good and is quite a common python idiom. You'll need `__init__.py` files in the directories but I expect you knew that.

Comment: What is your question?  The solution you describe should work fine.  Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: @wong2 no, there are multiple files in SubFileA and SubFileB. Where I plan to write all "from util*.py import *" in __init__.py, and in main.py I only have to write "from subFileA import *"

Answer (score 1):

You need to make each of the directories into a package for the `from <package> import ...` syntax to work. To tell Python a directory is a package, simply create an empty `__init__.py` file in each directory.

If you want specific behavior depending on the version of `util1` that is imported, you could write initialization code in each `__init__.py` file.

For more information, check the [official documentation on packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

---

Ultimately, your new project directory tree should look like this:

```
Files/ 
    main.py
    SubFileA/
        __init__.py
        util1.py
    SubFileB/
        __init__.py
        util1.py
```

Comment: Could you tell me more about "initialization code in each __init__.py"  ?

Comment: `__init__.py` is run when you import a package, much like the `__init__()` method is run when you instantiate an object. Take a look at how popular Python projects write their `__init__.py` files to get an idea of different approaches. I recommend you read [the official documentation on packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) if you want to learn more.